# Unable to click on QWidget with Qt:WindowStaysOnTopHint flag attribute - Mac only issue

Tags: qt

I have a class

```
class LocationLineEdit:public QLineEdit{
private:
QWidget* mpListPop;
MySuggestionList* mpLocationListView;
}
```

on a modal dialog, which includes a popup list:

```
class MySuggestionList:public MyAutoScrollArea {}
class MyAutoScrollArea:public QScrollArea {}
```

initialized as:

```
mpListPop=new QWidget(pParent, Qt:Tool | Qt:WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt:FramelessWindowHint);
mpLocationListView = new MySuggestionList(mpListPop);

pParent = parent dialog box (even for lineEdit)
```

This issue is only on Mac. The issue here is: I am unable to click on mpListPop (as soon as mpListPop is populated and shown) though the navigation keys (left and right) are working fine.
I can't go away with Qt::Tool. If I don't use Qt:WindowStaysOnTopHint, then mpListPop is shown behind parent widget (bug in Qt4.7 and fixed in Qt5.0. I am using Qt4.7) and using Qt:WindowStaysOnTopHint is a necessity for me.
On Widows, this implementation (even without Qt:WindowStaysOnTopHint flag)  is working perfectly fine.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in Advance.

~Andro

Comment: Is this issue this much complex, that there are no responses on it?